# SQL Server 2008 Express remote connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I have a connection string to connect to sql server express 2008

```
string ConnectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=mydb; user id=sa; password=12345qwerty";
```

this works normally
but when i want to remote connect using this connection string :

```
string ConnectionString = @"Server=119.225.128.211\SQLEXPRESS,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=mydb; user id=sa; password=12345qwerty";
```

the connection doesn't work and gives this error :
[image]

I followed this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx
and my firewall is off

Why can't I connect to SQL Server Express remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SO article may help you. Remote Connections are not configured by default:
[Remote connection to SQL Server Express fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020874/remote-connection-to-sql-server-express-fails?rq=1)